# React Js and React Router Dom multiple user types Private Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three different Users. I would want them to access different routes as per their role. I set a token and userRole in the localstorage and I would like to have my protected Route check the avaliability of token in the localstorage which is retrieved by redux.

```
const TeacherRoute =({ component: Component , auth, ...rest}) => (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render = {props =>{
        if(!props.token){
                    return <Redirect to="/login" />
        }else if(props.token !== null){
          if (props.userRole !== 'principal'){
            if (props.userRole === 'student'){
              return <Redirect to="/studentdashboard" />
            }else if(props.userRole ==='teacher'){
              return <Redirect to="/teacherdashboard" />
            }else{
              return <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
          }
                }else {
                    return < Component {...props} />;
                }
            }}

        />
    );

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    token: state.auth.token,
  userRole: state.auth.userRole,
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, )(TeacherRoute);
```

The challenge is that at first when I had the StudentRoute before adding the teacher and AdminRoute the route could redirect and disallow those who are not students to have access to the Student Route but the moment I added the other two Routes I got this error.

````
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.```

May you kindly help me fix this problem. Thanks in advance
````

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. Instead of delegating the role checking and token checking to the react Router we relied upon the Layout wrappers for all the dashboards. Since they control what is displayed in their children they were the perfect place to store our authentication Logic.